# Circular Pacelables

Tags: java, android, parcelable

In my code I have two classes, which contain instances of each other, both of which are Parcelable.

There is a "Server" class, which can own multiple "Channel" classes.  What I'm attempting to determine is did I just write an infinite loop into the `writeToParcel` and `createFromParcel` methods?

Here is some Code:

```
//Server implementations
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeStringArray(new String[] {
            NAME, 
            PASS, 
            PORT, 
            NICK, 
            ALT_NICK, 
            START_CHANNEL, 
            PORT, 
            WindowText});
    Bundle channelBundle = new Bundle();
    channelBundle.putParcelableArray("Channels", Channels);
    dest.writeBundle(channelBundle);
}
//...
public IRCServer createFromParcel(Parcel in)
    {
        IRCServer ret = new IRCServer();
        String[] Data = new String[8];
        in.readStringArray(Data);
        ret.NAME = Data[0];
        ret.PASS = Data[1];
        ret.PORT = Data[2];
        ret.NICK = Data[3];
        ret.ALT_NICK = Data[4];
        ret.START_CHANNEL = Data[5];
        ret.PORT = Data[6];
        ret.WindowText = Data[7];

        Bundle cBund = in.readBundle();
        ret.Channels = (IRCChannel[])cBund.getParcelableArray("Channels");

        return ret;
    }

//Channel Implementation
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeStringArray(new String[] {
        Name,
        WindowText
    });
    dest.writeStringList(UserList);
    Bundle ServerBundle = new Bundle();
    ServerBundle.putParcelable("Server", server);
    dest.writeBundle(ServerBundle);
}
//...
public IRCChannel createFromParcel(Parcel in)
    {
        IRCChannel ret = new IRCChannel();
        String[] Data = new String[2];
        in.readStringArray(Data);
        ret.Name = Data[0];
        ret.WindowText = Data[1];
        in.readStringList(ret.UserList);
        Bundle ser = in.readBundle();
        ret.server = (IRCServer)ser.getParcelable("Server");
        return ret;
    }
```

Some other notes:  Yes, the Server object inside channel is a backreference to the actual server object.  Yes, each of the Channel objects inside server contains this backreference.

Question: Will this code just loop infinitely creating parcels as soon as its told to do the first one, or is it actually safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's always servers owning multiple channels (and never a channel being owned by multiple servers, you should only write the server with its associated channels:

```
Server.writeToParcel:
    - write server identifier (name, fqdn, etc)
    - write user list
    - write channel count
    - for each channel: write channel

Channel.writeToParcel:
    - write channel name
    - write channel info
```

Then when you restore this, the server deserializes the parcel, creates a list of channels and reads each channel; `channel.server` can then be set to the server instance which reads the parcel.

(Sorry for the pseudo code, but you should get the idea)

Comment: That works rather well.   Dont bother parceling the server reference inside the channel object, just re-assign it afterwards.